# PyQt4, prevent app.exec_() from hanging the main thread

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I have some simple code that loads google.com with the PyQt4 library.
This is the code:

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication
from PyQt4.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import QWebView

class Browser(QWebView):
    def __init__(self):
        QWebView.__init__(self)
        self.loadFinished.connect(self._result_available)

    def _result_available(self, ok):
        frame = self.page().mainFrame()
        #print(frame.toHtml())
        app.exit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    view = Browser()
    view.load(QUrl('http://www.google.com'))
    print('start')
    app.exec_()#hangs the main thread
    print('end')
```

My problem with this code is that `app.exec_()` hangs the main thread for a while, between the print start and print end.
Is there a way to scrape a website in PyQt4 without making the main thread hang for a while.
I would like to resume the main thread's normal execution of code after `app.exec_()`.

Comment: In short, it doesn't work like this. Qt's intended as a GUI library, so `app.exec_()` essentially launches the GUI. You don't get control back to the thread like you want until the app exits. If you're wanting to just do an http get, you'd be much better off with a module like [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/). Qt is overkill.

Comment: @JCVanHamme. It's certainly not overkill if you need to run all the scripts, load the images, render the page etc. For that, some kind of gui is required, and you also need an event-loop to determine when the page has fully loaded.

Comment: The application is obviously not *hanging*. Do you seriously expect that a webpage and all its resources can be downloaded and rendered *instantaneously*?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably just taking time to download the content from the web. `app.exec_()` is what runs your application basically. So if anything is indeed hanging it's actually some other factor that influences the proper execution of your application. Any statements that are after the `app.exec_()` will be executed once you close the application. Usually `app.exec_()` is called at the end of the `main` (in C++ you do `return app.exec_()` which you can also do in PyQt of course).

When working with content that requires time to be downloaded and displayed in the UI, you have to add multithreading in order to allow the main thread to continue work properly (thus not creating the so called **UI freeze**) but at the same time do some work in the background. The sole purpose of the main thread is to keep track of the UI and run it. Anything else that you add to the main thread will prevent the UI from working in a fluent manner. You have several options here - inheriting `QThread` (I wouldn't suggest doing that for this scenario in particular), using `QThread + QObject` in order to incorporate slots and signal in your application (for example: page downloaded? -> if yes, signal the UI to display the content), `QRunnable` etc.

So my advice is to download the content in a separate thread and once it's done you can add it to your UI as well as provide some other form of visual feedback (this also includes `print` statements :P).

Comment: The issue here (if you look at some of the other questions the OP has posted on this topic), is that he wants the *complete webpage*, including the content in iframes. So it's not simply a matter of downloading one html document: he needs to actually load and render the *entire* webpage and all it's resources. And to do that, some of Qt's GUI classes are needed (such as `QWebPage`) - which obviously cannot safely operate outside the main thread.

Comment: I never said that the rendering of the downloaded page has to be done outside the main thread. :P Besides the question is about the blocking of the main thread and not about how exactly to render or to download a web page.

Comment: I was just trying to point out that several of the OPs questions on this topic are quite misleading. In his first question, he stated: "I would like to get the DOM of a website after js execution. I would also like to get all the content of the iframes in the website, similarly to what I have in Google Chrome's Inspect Element feature". And in another question, it seems he is actually trying (and failing) to run GUI code in a separate thread. I have now suggested to him that using a separate *process* might a be better approach.

Comment: Np. I haven't looked at his other question.

Comment: Yeah, I guessed that - which was the reason for my comments. I was trying to be helpful - not sure if you took it the wrong way.

Comment: Nah, I was just wondering what you're on about. :D Now I see what you mean so I am no longer confused. XD